# Regex help in Python for extracting specific string as given below

Tags: python, regex

extract string after 1008 and before hyphen in the following line

**ad - 1007-1008 qw rt v qw gh - 11/11/1008**

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I saw this is your first time asking a question on SO, hence would suggest you to quickly go through [How to put a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as someone suggested in comments too. You should show your efforts that you tried to solve the problem in your post here. It also increases the likelihood of others posting their answer as well as this may save your post from downvotes. Also, you should list the expected output vs actual output of your program to make it further clearer.

Nevertheless, I think I've got your question and although it appears a bit broad, and here is my solution. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

With those two conditions, you can use positive look ahead and positive look behind in following regex to capture the text you wanted,

```
(?<=1008).+(?=-)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PN9fbW/1)**

Python code demo,

```
import re

s = 'ad - 1007-1008 qw rt v qw gh - 11/11/1008'
print(re.search(r'(?<=1008).+(?=-)',s).group())
```

Prints,

```
 qw rt v qw gh
```

Similarly, a non-lookaround based solution will be the following, where you remove the lookarounds and instead use group to capture your intended text with following regex,

```
1008(.+)-
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PN9fbW/2/)**

Python code demo,

```
import re

s = 'ad - 1007-1008 qw rt v qw gh - 11/11/1008'
print(re.search(r'1008(.+)-',s).group(1))
```

Prints,

```
 qw rt v qw gh
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. And yes this is exactly what I was looking for. Ty:)

Comment: @Tanvi: Glad to know it helped you. Please consider marking my answer accepted by clicking the tick mark in the answer. Also check, [How accepting the answer works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)